# A question on limit of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $\varphi(n)$ is a positive monotone increasing function defined on $N$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}=0$. Let $\{n_k\}$ be a subsequence with $\lim_{k\to \infty}\frac{n_k}{n_{k+1}}=1.$ Can we get that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{\varphi(n_k)}{\varphi(n_{k+1})}=1$?

Comment: what is $\{n_{k}\}$ a subsequence of?

Comment: $\{n_k\}\subset N$, i.e., $\{n_k\}$ be a subsequence of natural numbers.

Answer (score 1):

No, not necessarily. One example of such a "subsequence" is $n_k=k$ itself, so your proposed conclusion would require that $\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{\phi(k)}{\phi(k+1)} = 1$. However this can fail, for example when
$$
\phi(k) = 2^{\lfloor \ln k\rfloor} < k^{\ln 2},
$$
for which $\frac{\phi(\lfloor e^j\rfloor)}{\phi(\lfloor e^j\rfloor+1)} = \frac12$ for all $j=1,2,\dots$.

Comment: Hello. Greg Martin, thank you for your answer. However, the function $\phi$ you given does not satisfy the condition $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\phi(n)}{n}=0$. Am I right?

Comment: It does satisfy that condition, thanks to the inequality $\phi(n) < n^{\ln 2}$, since $\ln 2<1$.